# Ionic Framework / .NET application sync?

Tags: javascript, .net, database, ionic-framework, nosql

I want to create a Android application (using Cordova/PhoneGap Ionic Framework, which means it's source code will be JavaScript + HTML + CSS and AngularJS as well. I need that app to sync to a cloud database service, but, I also have a .NET based project, which need to sync to the same database. I wanted to use like a Firebase-ish backend, that could manage all the database stuff, as I wrote only (at least mostly) front-end code for my app. Keeping in mind that I need a NoSQL database service.

To give an example:

I want my app to communicate with, let's say, CouchDB (IrisCouch on the cloud to be specific), and my .NET project to listen to the changes my app makes to the database, and handle them. What I need is a platform where I only need to call API's functions, or the closest I can get to that. I tried Firebase already, but that will get too expensive, as I need something cheaper, at least for now. Am I expecting too much? Do I really need to write server-side code in this case, and if so, which would you guys think it's the best way?

Answer (score 0):

For back-end you can use ASP.NET Web-API which supports ASP.NET Identity with OAuth login like Facebook, Twitter etc. and on front-end you can you use IonicFramework with AngularJs to call those API.

Helpful resources:

[ASP.NET](http://asp.net/web-api)
[IonicFramework](http://ionicframework.com)
[AngularJS](http://angularjs.org)
[Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) (Restful operations made easy for angular)